# General algorithm: random sort array, so the distance between objects is maxed

Tags: algorithm, sorting, random, shuffle

Given an array of random not-unique numbers

```
[221,44,12,334,63,842,112,12]
```

What would be the best approach to random sort the values, but also try to max the distance |A-B| to the neighbouring number

Comment: Do you mean the sum of |A-B| should be maximized?

Comment: Yes, the sum of |A-B| should be maximized

Comment: Should it be random, or should it maximize distances for adjacent cells? These are self contradicting.

Comment: @Benjy Kessler That's interesting; which reduction is your guess?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a suboptimal greedy algorithm:

```
1. sortedArr <- sort input array
2. resultArr <- initialize empty array
3. for i=0 to size of sortedArr
  a. if i%2
    I. resultArr[i] = sortedArr[i/2]
  b. else
    II. resultArr[i] = sortedArr[sortedArr.size - (i+1)/2]
```

This puts numbers in the result alternating from the left and right of the sorted input. For example if the sorted input is:

```
12, 12, 44, 63, 112, 221, 334, 842
```

Then the output would be:

```
12, 842, 12, 334, 44, 221, 63, 112
```

This might not be optimal but it probably gets pretty close and works in O(nlogn). On your example the optimal is obtained by:

```
63, 221, 12, 334, 12, 842, 44, 112
```

Which yields a sum of 2707. My algorithm yields a sum of 2656. I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to find the optimal in polynomial time.
A brute force solution in Python would look like:

```
import itertools
maxSum = 0
maxl = []
for l in itertools.permutations([221,44,12,334,63,842,112,12]):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(len(l)-1):
    sum += abs(l[i]-l[i+1])
  if sum > maxSum:
    print maxSum
    print maxl
    maxSum = sum
    maxl = l
print maxSum
print maxl
```